# page.goto request for web page keeps loading with networkidle0 in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

when is use

```
page.on('request', req => {
      try {
        const whitelist = ['document', 'script', 'xhr', 'fetch'];
        requestUrl = req.url();
        if (!whitelist.includes(req.resourceType())) {
          return req.abort();
        }
        req.continue();
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
await page.goto("https://b2b.qq.com/busin?keywords=%E8%BE%93%E9%80%81%E6%9C%BA" , {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0});
result = await page.content();
```

The request can not return any result.It looks like the page can not be loaded even with enough time.how can i debugger the puppeteer to find why it keeps loading and can not return result.

By the way, the url can be loaded in browser.

Comment: i found the page.on is execute in loop mode,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add console logs for req type and URL, you will see that the page infinitely try to load an image with URL `https://btrace.qq.com/kvcollect?...many tracing data`. Maybe site code checks this image and if it is not loaded it tries again infinitely.

Comment: As you said, i abort the image request,but the url above is a data report url.It will resend if been abort.Thank you.